# Wordpress Custom Post Type Default page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok I have made my custom post type and they work fine(code shown below). But I cant seem to make a default page for it for example example.com/php < how do I get that page. I can make pages like example.com/php/some page/ and they work fine.

```
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('PHP', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('PHP', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'PHP Page'),
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true, 
'show_in_menu' => true, 
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'has_archive' => true, 
'hierarchical' => true,
'menu_position' => null,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes')
 ); 
register_post_type('php',$args);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an intuitive way to do this in WordPress (you might want to check over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). However, I'll explain how I have done this before.

Create a new page template, say, `php.php`, with whatever you want the "default" page to do. Usually, I include a loop that only pulls from my custom post type.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: PHP Default Page
*/
// ...
query_posts("post_type=php");
// ...
?>
```

Then, create a page within the WordPress dashboard titled "PHP" (so it will have the permalink, `http://example.com/php`)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Just figured it out! In the template directory you can get this page by calling it archive-POSTTYPENAME.php so in my case archive-php.php this is then used for that page!

Comment: Great! I'm glad that worked for you. Now I know that there is a simpler way!